# Email service in Jhipster

Tags: spring, jhipster

I'm new to Jhispter and I created an application using the `yeoman generator` for Jhipster.

When I logged as an admin to this application to check the `Health checks` section I noticed that email service is down and the details says this :

```
com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: localhost, 25; timeout -1
```

How can I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 2):

You must fill properties in application-dev.yml or application-prod.yml with your real account data (eg gmail account)

```
    mail:
    host: localhost
    port: 25
    username:
    password:
```

Sample file:
https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app-token/blob/master/src/main/resources/config/application-dev.yml

Answer (score 0):

Go to application-prod.yml and add config below to fix it.

```
spring:
mail: 
    host: smtp.gmail.com
    port: 587
    user: your gmail address
    password: your password
    protocol: smtp
    tls: true
    auth: true
    from: spoonatte@gmail.com
    properties.mail.smtp:
        auth: true
        starttls.enable: true
        ssl.trust: smtp.gmail.com
```

OR in application-prod.yml

```
    mail:
    host: smtp.gmail.com
    port: 587
    username: your gmail address       
    password: your password           
    protocol: smtp
    tls: true
    properties.mail.smtp:
        auth: true
        starttls.enable: true
        ssl.trust: smtp.gmail.com
   messages:
    cache-seconds: 1
  thymeleaf:
    cache: false
```