# JHipster new User Registration -> MailConnectException

Tags: spring, exception, jhipster, user-registration, mail-sender

I am getting to know JHipster and Spring better and better but I have an issue with registrating a new User. When I try to register a new User I receive the below error message. According to this Stackoverflow issue [Email service in Jhipster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35956976/email-service-in-jhipster) I have to fill in the properties in application-dev.yml or application-prod.yml.

The web-app should be used from different persons, who should be able to register themselves. I don't think that this is the correct way to go? Am I missing something here? Do I need a SMTP Server for this to work?

```
2017-12-05 09:19:58.006  WARN 31208 --- [irpd-Executor-2] irpd.service.MailService                 : Email could not be sent to user 'test.test@gmail.com'

org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Mail server connection failed; nested exception is com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: localhost, 25; timeout -1;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect. Failed messages: com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: localhost, 25; timeout -1;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

I have the following entry in my application-dev.yaml:

```
 mail:
        host: localhost
        port: 25
        username:
        password:
    messages:
        cache-seconds: 1
    thymeleaf:
        cache: false
    http:
        multipart:
            max-file-size: 5MB
            max-request-size: 20MB
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need an SMTP server. Check our tips section on www.jhipster.tech, you'll find [how to configure email](http://www.jhipster.tech/tips/011_tip_configuring_email_in_jhipster.html) and [how to use MailDev with Docker](http://www.jhipster.tech/tips/015_tip_local_smtp_server.html)